# get exception data dictionary of C# in angular promise

Tags: c#, angularjs

I am writinig a REST application using C# and angularjs.
I need to access data from a exception thrown in C# with data.dictonary paramter using angular promise.

C#

```
public MessageObj signUp()
 {
           Exception exp = new Exception();
           exp.Data.Add("failType","duplicateID");
           throw exp;
 }
```

AngularJS

```
   promise = signupService.signup($scope.signupObj);
    promise.$promise.then(function (response) {
       alert("pass");
    }, function (response) {
       alert(response.data.failType);
       alert("fail");
    });
```

I am setting a key named failType in C# exception object and I want to access the failType in Angular promise onFailure method.

dot net framework 4.5
MVC4

Comment: So what's you problem? What doesn't work?

Comment: I need to get a some name/value pair on exception in front end. I want to throw the exception from C# with some name value pairs and I need to get it and display in angular. Does it clear ur question ??

Answer (score 0):

Angular won't get access to the exception when you're browsing from another machine. Instead of throwing the exception it's better to return any data you need and set an appropriate error code on the response to indicate failure:

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
```